# Probability for Subsets

Tags: probability

I am examining a set S, which is composed of a finite number known of elements. The size of the set is much larger than the number of possible types of elements, so each repeats many times.

I am interested in the behavior of various subsets of S. Suppose there are two subsets, A and B, in S. In particular, I am interested in the composition of the intersection of those two sets. However, not all the elements of S are known. A and B are both large enough to establish statistical significance, but the intersection of A and B is small.

My question is this: is there a well-formed way to infer the behavior of the intersection of A and B from the much larger data-sets of A, B, and S?